# C++field of struct if error

Tags: c++, if-statement, struct

What is hire wrong? Can someone please explain the issue to me? if statement is not working.

```
if(restavracija[i].ocena>restavracija[x].ocena){

                restavracija temp=restavracija[i];
                restavracija[i]=restavracija[x];
                restavracija[x]=temp;


            }

struct restavracija{
    char ime[50];
    char naslov[50];
    int o,z;
    int bon;
    int ocena;
};
```

Comment: What's the error? You should post a piece of code that's ideally runnable.

Comment: Without seeing all the relevant `struct` definitions, variable definitions, and the exact error message you're getting, we can't answer this question. Can you please update your question to include this information?

Comment: Can't post an answer as some silly people closed your question, but the problem is _very_ clear. `restavracija` is a _type_, not an _object_. You have to instantiate it.

Comment: @CrashDown: "grammer fixes" lol??!

Comment: restavracija polje[10];
like that in main?

Comment: @CrashDown: That'll do, yeah. There you create a nice array of 10 of them. Then, to use one of them, it's `polje[i]`, not `restavracija[i]`.

Comment: btw, you may use `std::swap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`restavracija` is a *type*, not an object. You have to instantiate it to produce an object.

In this particular case, it looks like you're expecting an array of them, and you want to call that array `polje`. Such an array declaration will look something like:

```
restavracija polje[10];
```

Accessing element `i` in that array will then look like:

```
polje[i]
```

Comment: How can I now change code to pointers to array of structure? I have no idea.

Comment: @CrashDown: What do you mean? And why?